# Total Structural Isomers of diphenyl chloromethane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, structural-formula, cis-trans-isomerism

[image: So the maximum answer can be 8. As per I know the condition for being structural Isomers is that the molecular formula has to be same]

[image: I started by drawing and just by changing the position I found so many , I am not getting this all of these are also structural isomers arent they ? What am I missing ?]

The maximum option is 8 available but while Drawing I found there are many more . Are there any other condition of structural formula except the fact that the compounds will have the same molecular formula but different structural formula?

Is there any other condition that I have to consider I think I am missing a point .

Comment: You were asked just to replace one hydrogen with chlorine, and **not** to rearrange the carbon skeleton.

Answer (score -1):

Starting from methane, $\ce{CH4}$, as point of departure,

- diphenyl methane (letter "d" as in Delta) has two phenyl groups that independently from each other are attached directly to this core ([cf.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphenylmethane)).  Which is the situation described on the questionary, and considered in your option in line A) which answers correctly the question.
- Alternatively, as a constitutional isomer, you may join one phenyl group to the next one (which then is called [biphenyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biphenyl), letter "b" as in Bravo), which in turn *as one group* is bound to the methyl group.  Which is what the is iterated in your options B), C), and D), departing from three different isomers of methyl-biphenyl, like [4-phenyltoluene](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/substance/4phenyltoluene1682364408611?lang=en&region=US).

As a side note -- even if options B), C), and D) *do not* correctly answer the questionary -- it is laudable that you started considering different positional isomers (i.e., the pattern of *ortho*-, *meta*-, *para*-substitution).